# Why uninstalling system apps through ADB cause problems like battery drain?

Tags: adb, battery, bloatware, realme

I have an Android 10 phone (realme) which came preinstalled with a lot of bloatwares. Few days ago I used adb to uninstall a lot of apps, like the default browser, file manager, facebook bloatwares, gallery etc. But now I am facing a noticeable battery drain. So now, I am thinking of factory resetting the device to get back those system apps. But this time after resetting, I am thinking of disabling those apps instead of uninstalling.

1. Will disabling them also affect the device the same way as uninstalling them do? I mean will I again face battery drain if I instead disable them?
2. And also, will disabling them free up the storage as uninstalling them do?
3. How can uninstalling system apps cause battery drain? Are those apps really helpful for the device so that they cause harm to the device when uninstalled?

Comment: May be you should name the apps and their package name you have uninstalled. Please edit your question and include this list, otherwise it is very difficult to guess why you encounter a battery drain. Additionally I would recommend to check `adb logcat` for errors occuring frequently.

Comment: Ok I will update my question soon.

Comment: I ran ```pm list packages -u``` and found that there are about 200 packages, I can't check all of them if they are uninstalled or not so I am going to reset device.